# Feature selection for sports prediction

Tags: predictive-models, feature-engineering

I worked through couple of projects on Kaggle to pick up machine learning. Now I am looking to implement a basic tennis prediction algorithm. I have a very beginner question.

Let's say, for each match, I collect 5 features for player A, 5 features for player B. My very basic understanding of machine learning tells me that from the perspective of a machine, these features are not players specific. In other words, there are simply 10 features. Is this correct? In this case, is it generally better to substitute these 10 features with differences between corresponding pairs of features, resulting in 5 features.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further?  Why are the features taken for Player A different from that of Player B?

Comment: Hey @Phil, I know it is very old thread. If you are still checking this SE site, can you please share which approach worked best for you?

Answer (score 3):

From the question I presume you mean that you take the same features from both player A and B - such as percentage of games previously won. Let's refer to each of these features as $X_1$ through to $X_k$. Usually we represent this in a matrix format such as,

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
Player & X_1 & X_2 & \dots & X_k \\
\hline
A &4 &3 &\dots & 6\\
\hline
B &6 &9 & \dots &1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

I just added arbitrary values in the table above. We usually say the number of features is $k$ and the number of players is $n$ which is 2 in this case. Finding the difference between pairs of features will still leave us with $k$ features.

The point which you seem to be making is that in the case of two players, if we use a machine learning tachnique which only uses the difference between features to make estimates then we may be wasteful in storing this $n\times k$ matrix. However this idea does not scale well. For example imagine we have 1000 players we would have to store the difference between the first player and all 999 other players, the second player and all 998 other players and so on. In general this would require $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}k$ values to be stored as opposed to $nk$.

While this is indeed required in some machine learning techniques, where covariance matrices are required, generally it is not and may be wasteful.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I agree with your comments as the number of features are not reduced by using difference.                  A little more info on what I am trying to accomplish. I am wirting the algorithm for low level professional tennis where there may not be much record of each players. So, I want to to basically generalize each player into a set of features of age, height, playing style, leftie/rightie, etc. And each match will be modelled as two players, and each with a set of abovementioed features.

Comment: Let's say I use two featuers for each player, age and height. And I theorize that the younger or taller player has higher probability to win. Do I construct each match as p1_age, p1_height, p2_age, p2_height ---> p1 wins, and so on. Or should I construct each match as p1_age-p2_age, p1_height-p2_height --> p1 wins?

Comment: @Phil in this case you can really do either. Keep in mind you probably want to have symmetry constraints. This can be easily encoded using kernel methods for example. It is hard to give further advice without knowing how you are modelling the system.

Comment: Another follow-up based on my very limited understanding of machine learning. If I hypothesize that a leftie can beat righty, given two features of A (player one's handedness) and B (player two's handedness), I can see an algorithm eventually confirming or rejecting my hypothesis. However, if I hypothesize that a taller player can beat a shorter player, given two features of A (player one's height) and B (player two’s height), I don't see how the machine algorithm can ever reach a conclusion without me creating a feature based on the height difference of two players.